# VBA Updation of MS Access database with a substring in a string

Tags: vba

I have the following sql which I am trying to update through Excel VBA to MS Access database.

```
strSQL = "update validations set where_clause =  'purp_cd in('P1590','S1590','P1591','S1591')' 
where row_id = 37"
```

This give a syntax error. I would like to get the syntax error eliminated

Help is sought from experts in this group

Venugopal

Answer (score 0):

You have quotes inside your quoted string. Try double quoting the values:

```
strSQL = "update validations set where_clause = 'purp_cd in (''P1590'', ''S1590'', ''P1591'', ''S1591'')' where row_id = 37"
```